# Multi-Container Docker Application - Internal Rest API Communication

Tags: azure, api, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I've created a multi-container docker application, that is hosted on an azure Linux app service for containers using docker compose, across images pulled from an azure container registry.

My application consists of a web app front end along with, at the moment, 3 API projects. I have deployed all these apps but I'm having problems getting the web app to communicate with the APIs. As I've only recently deployed the web app and other apps, I have been using my localhost endpoint for the API calls. This has been working fine to test the functionalities of the APIs with my front end, however as I am now deploying my project, I need to communicate with services within the container, but everything I try doesn't seem to work as expected, resulting in a 500 internal server error.

My docker-compose file for dev is below:

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  webapp:
    image: {MyApp}.azurecr.io/{ProjectName}:dev
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      {ProjectName}-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.1
    depends_on:
      - {App1}.api
      - {App2}.api
      - {App3}.api

  {App1}.api:
    image: {MyApp}.azurecr.io/{App1}api:dev
    container_name: {App1}
    ports: 
      - "2000:2000"
    networks:
      {ProjectName}-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.2
    depends_on:
      - xamlbuilder.api

  {App2}.api:
    image: {MyApp}.azurecr.io/{App2}:dev
    container_name: {App2}
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      {ProjectName}-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.3

  {App3}.api:
    image: {MyApp}.azurecr.io/{App3}:dev
    container_name: {App3}
    ports: 
      - "4000:4000"
    networks:
      {ProjectName}-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.4

networks:
  {ProjectName}-net:
    ipam:
      driver: bridge
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
```

DockerFile (webapp):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0 AS build
WORKDIR /source

COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore

RUN dotnet publish --output /app/ --configuration Release --no-restore

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "{ProjectName}.WebApp.dll"]
EXPOSE 80
```

Dockerfile {App1}

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0 AS build
WORKDIR /source

COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore

RUN dotnet publish --output /app/ --configuration Release --no-restore

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "{ProjectName}.{App1}.API.dll"]
EXPOSE 2000
```

(other apps are similar dockerfiles)

My latest attempt was adding the network configuration and static IP Addresses as we could not get it working. I don't know whether this issue is with my end point (I have tried replacing my localhost endpoints with all manner of endpoints - URL/app1:portNumber/Methods, URL/app1/Methods, IPAddress:portNumber/Methods, IPAddress/Methods etc).

Can anyone see anything blindingly obvious? Have I just used the wrong endpoints or is it a compose/dockerfile/config issue?

Many thanks for any guidance!

Comment: Does it run successfully in your local machine?

Comment: not when I'm trying to use the container endpoints. only when im using localhost and running the services locally

Comment: Do you mean it runs well locally but not well when you deploy to the azure web app with containers?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: _I have tried replacing my localhost endpoints with all manner of endpoints_ wow... You know localhost is a loopback interface for a computer to connect to itself? In Docker you usually use the container name as host, so `http://{App1}:{yourEXPOSEDport}/app1/Methods`. The exposed port is not necessary the same as the port the app starts within the container, see your composer file. `"4000:4000"` means redirect container port 4000 to outside port 4000, so you need to call that in the URL too. or change the exposed port

Comment: iirc `EXPOSE 2000` is kinda discouraged these days and people should be using `-p m:n` instead (or via compose file). So if you want have it reachable at port 80 you do `ports: "80:2000"`, see the docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? Please let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Not yet no, I've tried Tseng's suggestion as well as editing the dockerfile as you have linked below, but still haven't had any luck getting a response

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes, go accept it as the answer.

Comment: Do you solve the problem? or for more help?

Comment: I did solve it yes. My docker file did work, but the api was listening to the port correctly (doh!) many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I see from the docker-compose file that you provide, you set the `networks` property in it. But the `networks` property is not supported in Azure Web App for Container currently. It possibly causes the problem when you use it but it is ignored by Azure Web App. See the [Docker Compose options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container#docker-compose-options) to find which is supported and which is not.

And additional, Azure Web App only supports to expose the port 80 or 443 to the Internet. You cannot expose other ports such as 3000 and 2000 in your file to the Internet.

You can take a look at the example that [Create a multi-container (preview) app in Web App for Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-multi-container-app). I think it's helpful to you.